# Dynamic Subfolder Paths - folder does not exist even after updating asset directories in settings

Tags: assets, slug

I have an asset directory which is set to

```
{basePath}assets/images/products/
```

I know my basePath is right as it works on other asset sources.

My entry upload location for products is set to:

```
{slug}/static/studio
```

However I get the following error when uploading assets:

```
upload failed. error uploading the file: The folder "/var/www/html/assets/images/products/carambola-earrings/static/studio/" does not exist
```

I have tried 'updating asset indexes'. But no luck. I have also double checked that the assets/images/products/ directory exists.

I am also checked the permissions are set to '775' for '/var/www/html'

Any help greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Is the Asset field you're setting the `{slug}/static/studio` upload location inside of a Matrix field or stand-alone?

Comment: Also, who is the user:group owner of `/var/www/html/assets` and what user:group is your web server running as?

Comment: The asset field is not in a matrix.. its just a regular entry field in the product. 
The server is running as root. here is the folder permissions:
    `drwxrwxr-x 2 root     root       4096 Sep 29 08:31 products`

my assets folder is set to

    `drwxrwxr-x 9 www-data www-data 4096 Sep 20 10:31 assets`

Comment: Any reason your web server isn't running as www-data:www-data? That'll probably solve your issue so you don't have to open up permissions to 777.

Comment: I have now tried changing all to www-data:www-data by using the following command. 
`sudo chown www-data:www-data -R html`
still no luck though unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so I have figured out why this wasn't working. 
When clicking on reset asset indexes It was always popping up an alert saying that another asset was missing. I already knew this, and it was something I intended on dealing with later. So I clicked OK and as the progress indicator continued to run along with the Tick Icon, I assumed it continued to update everything else, skipping over the error.
But it turns out this isn't the case. The function halts at the error. So once I fixed this other missing asset, everything worked.
It is a little misleading having the progress animation and tick icon still work when in fact nothing is happening.
thanks for all your help. :)

Comment: Thanks great find, ridiculous issue, terrible error reporting